# How to change active link color in bootstrap css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using joomla 3 and bootstrap.min.js
I am creating menu and giving special class in order to change hover, active, visited links and style of the menu.
I could not find how to change active link color of menu. 
Suppose I have 2 menu. Home and Contact.
When I am in Home it is red, I want to change this color.
I could change a:active and a:hover. 
Here is code;

```
.topmenu .active a,
.topmenu .active a:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
.topmenu > li > a{
    color: orange;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.topmenu > li > a:hover {
    color: black;
    background:white;
}
```

Even I used div to change color of active link.
Here is code

```
#top-menu a{
background-color: white;
color: orange;
font-weight:bold;
}
#top-menu a:focus
{
    color: orange;
}
#top-menu a:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

Every time when I click to Home it is activated and the color is red. What I want to change it to orange. Can not find how to do it.

Here is my markup code

```
<div id="top-menu">
<ul class="nav menu nav-pills topmenu">
<li class="item-109 current active"><a href="/joomla3/">Home</a></li>
<li class="item-138"><a href="/joomla3/?Itemid=138"> Russian </a></li>
<li class="item-110"><a href="/joomla3/?Itemid=110"></a></li></ul>
</div>
```

What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: dont alter bootstrap. Include bootstrap,css and below that include your custom css , where u overrride the existing style

Comment: How to override current active link color?

Comment: Open in firefox--> Inspect in firefox , See the class which is affecting the color in the CSS panel, copy that class, change the color and put it in ur new css

Comment: Did not help. It is giving me class="item-109 current active"

Comment: My css is .item-109  {
    color: white;
}

Comment: So far all 3 answers you have should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally with experiments I found how to capture it.

```
#top-menu .current a
{
    color: orange !important;
}
```

Thank you everyone for your time and help.
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

In order to do what your are trying to do you must first understand  **a:hover Must**   come after  **a:link**  and  **a:visited** in the CSS definition in order to be effective. If they are not in this order then they will not work.
Second is you must understand that if you where thinking (a:active) meant the color of the current link the end user was on, this is incorrect. (a:active) changes the color when you click on the link. You can test this by holding down the mouse button on the link that you made a different color with the (a:active).
Finally, if you are trying to do this using just CSS you have to add a specific class on the current link  that the end user is on. Below I left you an example hope this helps :)

Your Navigation Bar As Follows
-Home
-Russia
-Italy

We are on the Italy Page For This Example:

```css
/*YOUR CSS SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS*/

/* unvisited link grey */
#top-menu a:link {
 color: #777;
}
/* visited link grey */
#top-menu a:visited {
 color: #777;
}
/* mouse over link blue */
#top-menu a:hover {
 color: #0CF;
}
/* selected link blue */
#top-menu a:active {
 color: #0CF;
}
/* !IMPORTANT ONLY ADD THIS CLASS TO YOUR ACTIVE PAGE LINK ( Color Blue )*/
.activePage a {
 color: #0CF !important
}
```

```html
<div id="top-menu">
  <ul class="nav menu nav-pills topmenu">
    <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/page1.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/page2.html">Russian</a></li>
    <li class="activePage"><a href="http://yourdomain.com/page3.html">Italy</a></li><!--Page End User Is On-->
    <!--Look UP ^^^^^^^^ Hope this helps :)-->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Notice I did not put the .activePage tag in the other links? What this does is allow your original colors that you choose in your css for your navigation bar to still take place while the page that is active stays solid with a different color.

The reason this worked is because I added **!important** at the end of the color for that separate class.

```css
.activePage {
  color: #0CF !important
}
```

So to apply this same technique to your other pages it would simply look like this:

Home Page

```css
/*YOUR CSS SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS*/

/* unvisited link grey */
#top-menu a:link {
 color: #777;
}
/* visited link grey */
#top-menu a:visited {
 color: #777;
}
/* mouse over link blue */
#top-menu a:hover {
 color: #0CF;
}
/* selected link blue */
#top-menu a:active {
 color: #0CF;
}
/* !IMPORTANT ONLY ADD THIS CLASS TO YOUR ACTIVE PAGE LINK ( Color Blue )*/
.activePage a {
 color: #0CF !important
}
```

```html
<div id="top-menu">
  <ul class="nav menu nav-pills topmenu">
    <li class="activePage"><a href="http://yourdomain.com/page1.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/page2.html">Russian</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/page3.html">Italy</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope I gave you a solid answer to your question because I hate it when I look all over the web and can't truly find the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you creating an `ID (#)` selector locally for the `Div` that contains the `a` links, then take that `id` name in your style-sheet and override the existing rule.

For instance,

```
#abc a{xxx:xxx;}
#abc a:active{xxx:xxx;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle link or the demo link to the website (if feasible) where the code is? - @FirdavsKurbonov

Comment: The website is in my local machine. About fiddle link, I am sorry, I heard about it for the first time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/  You can paste your code in this website, click update and send us the updated URL that will highlight your issue.

Comment: Fiddle doesn't convey your issue. See if you can test upload your website and send the link. - @FirdavsKurbonov

Comment: I have included menu in my question see it. I updated it. I will put whole source code now in jsFiddle.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov Hold off on that - I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pb7U6/1/

Comment: Did you change something? I can't see changes.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov Links are orange in the fiddle (note the `/1` at the end; that's how jsFiddle manages change history) - I suspect there is something in your Joomla theme that is over-riding this.

Comment: Change this in your css. From `#top-menu a:focus` to `div#top-menu a:focus` - @FirdavsKurbonov

Comment: @NathanLee it is still the same.

Comment: @TiesonT. Thanks Tieson, I will dig into my template and see what is hapenning

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov Get Firebug if you don't have it already (it's a Firefox plugin, plus there are Lite versions for other browsers). Use the Inspect tool on the menu - it will tell you what rules are being applied.

Comment: I am using these kind of staff. But the problem is lack of knowledge in bootstrap and css:)

Answer (score 4):

For change the current active link color we can use code in external css file or inline css

```
.active a
{
background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Fix navigation menu active links
$(document).ready(function(){
    var path = window.location.pathname,
        link = window.location.href
    ;
    $('a[href="'+path+'"], a[href="'+link+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping a block of code, can you try to explain what the code does and why it works?

Answer (score 1):

```
        $(function (){
            $('nav ul li a.sub-menu').each(function(){
                var path = window.location.href;
                var current = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                if(url == current){
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                };
            });     
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to globally change the link colors (or pretty much anything else), create a customized download: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

In response to your comment, if you want to override the supplied CSS, you need to create a rule that is more specific. So, either create a selector like `#my-custom-container .item-109 .current .active` or add a `!important` to your rule(s) for `.item-109 .current .active`

Comment: No, I want to change it locally. Can not find how to capture it. If I inspect the object it is showing like this "item-109 current active".

Comment: Does not work. I tried to change it using !important. No changes.

Comment: "Does not work" isn't terribly helpful. Can you update your question to include what you've tried so far?

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov The selectors you're using are less specific than what Bootstrap is using, so even if your CSS is included after, Bootstrap still wins. Give me a moment and I'll create a jsFiddle for you. Is this for the navbar or the nav?

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov Can you add a snippet of the markup for the menu to your question? The links themselves are unimportant; just need to know the structure of your menu.

Comment: Updated my question. See it.

Comment: *"These docs are for v2.3.2, which is no longer officially supported"* the bootstrap link showed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS to `.item-109 { color: white !important; }`.

[Here's a link with more information on `!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules).

Comment: Something strange is happening with my css. It is not working.

Comment: Is this page live? If so PM me a link and I'll see if I can tell what's going on.

Comment: It is in my local machine. Under development. I can send you image of it. But I think it does not help you.

Comment: How about loading the page, opening the inspector and uploading a screenshot of the inspection window so we can see the class names and such? That may help.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick (2023)

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var path = window.location.href;
    $("a.list-group-item").each(function(item){
        var path = window.location.href;
        var urlSegment = $(this).attr('href').lastIndexOf('/')+1;

        var urlPath = $(this).attr('href').substring(urlSegment)

        var current = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

        if(current == urlPath){
            console.log('yeahhh')
            $("a.list-group-item.active").removeClass('active')
            $(this).addClass('active')
        }

    })

});
```

Answer (score -2):

first add `php` code in link

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link <?php if(PAGE == 'index') { echo 'active'; } ?>" href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link <?php if(PAGE == 'about-us') { echo 'active'; } ?>" href="about-us.php">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link <?php if(PAGE == 'contact-us') { echo 'active'; } ?>" href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
```

then in every page